# How to programmatically remove NIR blocking filter from Android camera

Tags: android, camera

My camera app has the ability to toggle on/off Night vision and thus NIR blocking filter. So there must be a way to do this programmatically, but I can't find how. Could anybody give me a clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

configure with

- Camera.getParameter
- Camera.setParameter

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html